# How to listen to navigate event?

Tags: reactjs, href

**Problem**: I would like to use callback functions based on changes in href when user navigates within the same page.

For example, i would like to use a callback when a user navigates out of the component (changing href from localhost:3000/user to localhost:3000/about)

I've tried

- **popstate** (which works when using forward/backward)
- **unload**(works when i refresh)
- **pagehide/pageshow** did not seem to respond at all.
- **visibilitychange** fired whenever i moved out of the tab, but it was not what I was looking for.

Comment: if your using react you just need a useeffect when the component is loaded... whats your environment setting?

Comment: The example hrefs are not "within the same page". You can have the same application (SPA), but these are different "routes". You can use React router to work with these, this a tool specifically designed for a case like this.

Comment: @Michael  i'm trying to use it when the component unmounts. i don't think listening to window event is the way to go. i've been trying to use div ref with useRef

Comment: did you try using the useffect cleanup function ? ( function executed when unmounting?

Comment: @Michael        actually, the cleanup function worked a lot better than event listener. thank you so much for the help! i don't know why i didn't think of that.

Comment: Glad to hear :) I will post an official answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the useEffect cleanup function to trigger logic when the component unmounts.

```
useEffect(() => {
        effect
        return () => {
            cleanup
        }
    }, [input])
```